# Silent error and 500 page instead of debug output in development on Haml::SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, haml

Got a weird issue. Seems something very simple..

The issue is when I make a Syntax error in HAML or ERB template in my Rails app, it renders 500 error page and no debug output with the error details. **BUT** if I simulate another type of error, for example

```
form_for -> for m_for (add whitespace in helper)
```

I receive error page I expect. http://cl.ly/image/1b1K3c1a0G3w

Versions:

- Rails v3.2.12 (tried to upgrade to 3.2.14)
- Ruby 1.9.3-p448
- HAML 3.1.7(tried 4.x.x) - but no debug output not only in HAML, erb template also does the same

The encoding of all files is US-ASCII

Trued to use magic_encoding gem - no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in splunk(http://www.splunk.com/) - errors collector. It catch exceptions from views without any notification in development mode. Issue was solved by moving in out in production group.

Also `gem better_errors` helped to catch errors in any way with and without splunk.